# mongoose 'minimize' empty nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a mongoose schema which contains multiple level nested properties. It is here:

```
var Person = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    parents: {
        mom: {
            name: String,
            birthYear: Number
        },
        dad: {
            name: String,
            birthYear: Number
        }
    }
});
```

In my example there can be 2 cases of the document state:

- every attributes has to be set in the `parents` object
- the `parents` object has to be full empty `{}`

My problem is that if the `parent` object is empty, the document is stored like this:

```
{
    name: 'Some Buddy',
    parents: {
        mom: {},
        dad: {}
    }
}
```

While the expected data should be this:

```
{
    name: 'Some Buddy'
    parents: {}
}
```

I've read a lot about `minimize: true` but it does not serve me a complete solution, because the `parents` object is not saved at all. So in short I would like to minimize every empty nested attributes (except for top-level attributes).

Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to achieve exactly what you want through Mongoose schema rules. What is the problem with having parents have empty `mom` and `dad` versus being empty? It seems like you can work around it very simply with client code.

Answer (score 1):

Same happens to me. In the schema below, starred is not initialized

```
Schema({minimize: false})
export class User {
    @Prop()
    _id: Number;

    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    sessionId: string;

    @Prop()
    _token: string;

    @Prop({type: mSchema.Types.Map})
    starred: {
        type: mSchema.Types.Map,
        of: starred,
        default: {}
    };
}

export interface starred {
    owner: string;
    repo: Number;
    tags: string[];
}
```

MongoDB output after a run

```
{"_id":{"$numberInt":"id"},"name":"name","sessionId":"wPEOw6vL0oTHKKav2nSlRg==","_token":"token","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My array of objects is also empty, although I exclude the "minimize" option:

I've done a lot of research but can't figure out how to fix this problem

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  
 
const DateSchema = { type: Date, required: false, default: new Date(false) };
const NumberSchema = { type: Number, required: false, default: 1 };
const StringSchema = { type: String, required: false, default: "" };
 
const CustomSchema = {
        tempoaSchedaInOre: DateSchema,
        tempoTotaleInOre: DateSchema       
};
const fasiSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
        utente: StringSchema,
 
        fase: [{        
        controlloMateriale : CustomSchema,
        equipaggiamentog : CustomSchema  
        }]
        } 
 ,{ minimize: false } //Crea componenti anche se vuoti
);
 
mongoose.model('fasi',fasiSchema);
```

In MongoDb generate this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5fddcffbada9d34460510774"},"utente":"","fase":[],"__v":0}
```